# how to make a select query with functions pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, stored-functions

Function 1:

```
create or replace function get_books (l_id in number)
return varchar
is l_return varchar2(100);
begin
select books into l_return from people where id=l_id;
return l_return;
end
/
```

Function 2:

```
create or replace function  get_author (l_id in number)
return varchar
is l_return varchar2(100);
begin
select author in l_return from authors where id=l_id;
return l_return;
end
/
```

I want to make a select with 2 functions, I want to display books and authors.
is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For example:

```
select get_books (1) book,
       get_author(1) author
from dual;
```

Presumably, both functions return a single value. If any of those selects (used in functions) returns more than one row, it'll fail.

---

As of the procedure: code you posted is invalid so I fixed it.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure get_categories (l_categories  in     varchar2,
  2                                              l_id          in     number,
  3                                              l_boolean        out boolean,
  4                                              l_error          out varchar2)
  5  is
  6  begin
  7  --   INSERT INTO categories (id, categories)
  8  --        VALUES (l_categories, l_id);
  9
 10     l_boolean := true;
 11     commit;
 12  exception
 13     when others
 14     then
 15        l_boolean := false;
 16        l_error := sqlerrm;
 17  end;
 18  /

Procedure created.
```

As it returns 2 OUT parameters, you have to declare variables to accept those values (`v_boolean` and `v_error`). Furthermore, as you can't directly display Boolean value, use `CASE` and display a *string* instead.

Procedure can't be called as a function within the SQL `SELECT` statement so you have to use another PL/SQL piece of code; an anonymous PL/SQL block is OK.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    v_categories varchar2(10) := 'ABC';
  3    v_id         number := 1;
  4    v_boolean    boolean;
  5    v_error      varchar2(200);
  6  begin
  7    get_categories(l_categories => v_categories,
  8                   l_id         => v_id,
  9                   l_boolean    => v_boolean,
 10                   l_error      => v_error
 11                  );
 12
 13    dbms_output.put_line(case when v_boolean then 'true' else 'false' end ||' - '||
 14                            v_error
 15                           );
 16  end;
 17  /
true -

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: i have those functions and a procedure get_categories,
how can I introduce the procedure? I have a package with this functions and procedures, and i need to extrag the informations with a query. can you help me ? 
I can't find on the internet how to do it

Comment: It depends on what that the procedure does and which kind of data it returns and how.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_categories (l_categories   IN     VARCHAR2,
                                            l_id           IN     NUMBER,
                                            l_boolean         OUT BOOLEAN,
                                            l_error           OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO categories (id, categories)
        VALUES (l_categories, l_id);

   l_bool := TRUE;
   COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      l_bool := FALSE;
      l_error := SQLERMM;
END;

Comment: this is the procedure.

Comment: You could write a function that calls the procedure and returns some SQL-friendly type. However, it can only return one value (or an object type with multiple attributes, but I think that would probably be overkill here).